# How to enable nested vt-x on windows 11 in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-11

The virtualization technology is already enabled in my bios setting of HP laptop i5 processor.

[image: Bios settings]

But "enable nested vt-x" option is still greyed out. Could anyone please suggest.

The base os I am using is windows 11 home. 64bit.

Comment: Off the top of my head, that sometimes acts up if hyper V is installed/enabled - could you see if it is?

Comment: What generation of i5 do you actually have? Not all CPUs that support VT-x actually support _nested_ VT-x.

Comment: this is the product: https://www.hp.com/in-en/shop/hp-laptop-15s-fq2071tu-360l4pa.html

Answer (score -1):

This is because only one hypervisor can use nested VT-x/AMD-v.
On Windows 11, Hyper-V is installed and enabled by default.

You need to disable Hyper-V to use vt with virtualbox.

1. goto windows 11 `settings -> apps -> optional features -> more windows features`
2. find and uncheck `windows hypervisor platform`
3. reboot

Comment: doesn't work, this is wrong on some machines.